# Normal map artifacts in Substance Painter

Tags: texture-baking, normal-map, artifacts

I am getting artifacts in my normal map when baking high poly to low poly in Substance Painter. I already discovered one thing that can cause these is that the high and low poly objects match too much, so I removed the objects that were extremely similar from the high poly and used Mark Sharp and Edge Split to get the desired affect. However, when I bake the normal map now, I'm getting different issues on the objects that aren't in the high poly.

The rails and main body of the gun are not in the high poly but I'm still getting these artifacts and strange lighting. They look perfect before bake.

[image: The rails and main body of the gun are not in the high poly but I'm still getting these artifacts and strange lighting. They look perfect before bake.]

I'm also getting this strange projection of the sling hook onto the rail of the stock that shouldn't be there. The models for the sling hook, rail, and stock are all in the exact same location in Blender so I don't understand why this projection is appearing. Here are a few more artifacts on the main body that shouldn't be there as well.

[image]

Thanks in advance for any help.